# Can’t catch ‘hidden.bs.modal’ in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, laravel-mix

I'm using `vue.js` in Laravel projoct and it can't catch `hidden.bs.modal` event.

This problem will appear when use `autoload` in `laravel-mix` and catch `hidden.bs.modal` in `vue.js`. (Out of `vue.js` is fine)

## Mix file

```
mix
.autoload({
    'jquery': ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
    'moment': ['moment','window.moment'],
})
...
```

I must to use `autoload` for solve problem when use package `pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker` with `laravel-mix`.

## Vue file

```
<template>
    <div id="my_modal"
         class="modal"
         tabindex="-1"
         role="dialog"
         aria-hidden="true"
         ref="my_modal">
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            $(this.$refs.my_modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', this.doSomething);
        },

        methods: {
            doSomething() {
                // Do something
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

So If I remove `autoload` from `webpack.mix.js`, I can catch the event. But package `pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker` will not working. What happens? Thanks.

Comment: i suggest to use native vue bootstrap component like https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

Answer (score -2):

you can catch it like this

```
<div ref="myModalRef"></div>

$(this.$refs.myModalRef).modal('hide')
```

or

```
$(this.$refs.myModalRef).modal('show')
```

but it will give you console.log error because its using JQuery.... still i didn't find ana answer to it but i will tell you when i know

Comment: This is incorrect. `hide` and `show` are _methods_ on the Bootstrap modal component that, well, hide and show the target modal respectively.

Comment: i don't understand. do you mean that its incorrect in the sense it doesn't work, or incorrect in the sense that its a bad practice ??

Comment: It’s incorrect as in it will not do what the OP wants. You can read what `show` and `hide` does on the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modalshow